# Jquery load hidden div into a popup div

Tags: jquery, css, django, load

I have the following django code that loops over all of my objects and creates a hidden div that i wish to show in a popup container.

My popup container works well, I just don't know how to do three things:

1. I want to hide whatever content is in the container
2. then I want to load the content into the container
3. then I want to set the display of the content to block once it is
   loaded in the popup

**django code**

```
    {% for recipe in recipe_list %}
            <div class="recipe">
                <div class="button">
                      click me to load recipe content
                    </div>

            <div id="recipepopup" style="display:none;">
                       //content
            </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div id = "popupdiv">
    <div id = "content_to_hide">
     //content to hide on recipepopup load
    </div>
    </div>
```

**And the Javascript for the click:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
      // hide current content in popupdiv 
      // then load recipepopup then set display
      // of recipepopup to block  
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you replaced your django with actual human readable HTML ?

Comment: You already had everything thought out in pseudo-code... I highly suggest you actually learn how to do things yourself from the jquery documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) instead of asking others how to do it.

Comment: @katiebekell, the `<div class="recipe">` is not closed on that post, check if it was a typo or a real issue on your document.

Comment: it was just a typo thanks zuul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner will work !

```
$("#popupdiv").children(':first').hide().end().append($('#recipepopup')).find('#recipepopup').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content_to_hide").hide();
var popup = $("#recipepopup");
$("#popupdiv").append(popup);
popup.show();
```

Just quickly put that together based on what you need. Should go in the button click code.